# React native pager view update items and scroll to first index

Tags: react-native, react-native-pager-view

I have problem and not quite sure how to fix it properly. I have N number of slides in my react native pager view and all works fine and performant. Now, i can add new slide in list and if I am on on index 1 or 2 in pager view it works correctly add new slide into state and scroll to index 0. All as expected. But. When i am on index 0 and add new slide it does not make any change. I need to swipe to index 1 than get back and i see my slide is added. Any maybe idea how to make this to work?!

Comment: Ah SO seems to be my rubber duck. I just add key prop in react-native-pager-view and all works fine. Magic :)